# jquery-mobile button not displaying in script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I have the following code which works as expected, except for the fact that the mobile button is not displaying.

```
div id="items">     
 <script id="item-template"  type="text/template">    
         <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" {[ print( done ?  '' : 'checked') ]} />
         <span class="text">{{ text}}</span> 
         <a id="save" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon='plus'>Save</a>
```

I have tried printing out the button etc, but does the querymobile button not work within a script?

cheers for any advice

Comment: So your saying, once I have passed all the values from backbone, I then need to refresh the div conatining the data?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function to the template and call it on `onclick` event like this:

```
var tpl = _.template( $("#item-template").html(), {fn : function() {alert("clicked!");} );
```

and in template:

```
<a href="#" id="save" onclick="<% fn() %>" > Save </a>
```

Comment: Sorry for slow response, what you be the benefit of passing a function back like this. Can it be automated?

Comment: Oops! Sorry for that. I think you used undersocre.js as template engine!